# Pandas Step function with rank

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I am trying to rank a column with the following function:

`f(x) = if x=0, then y=0 else if x<0 then y=0.5 else y=rank(x)` 
Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Comment: What difficulties are you coming across?

Comment: I I can only run it with one condition.            
x[col] = x[x[col]>0].rank(pct=True, method='average')
x = x.fillna(0)

Comment: So overwrite the relevant portions with the other things you want.

Comment: but in that case, I don't know where the 0s and where the negatives.

Comment: Filter for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic indexing

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [2, 3, 1, -1, 0]})
df["y"] = df["x"].rank()
df["y"][df["x"] == 0] = 0
df["y"][df["x"] < 0] = .5
```

or `loc`

```
df["y"] = df["x"].rank()
df.loc[df["x"] == 0, "y"] = 0
df.loc[df["x"] < 0, "y"] = .5
```

or multiple `.where` conditions

```
df["y"] = df["x"].where(df["x"] == 0, df["x"].rank().where(df["x"] > 0, .5))
```

Answer (score 1):

So you say that you have your ranks already (with `x` being a data frame and `col` being the column name):

```
x[col] = x[x[col]>0].rank(pct=True, method='average')
x = x.fillna(0)
```

Patch to include your other conditions:

```
x[col] = np.where(x[col] < 0, 0.5, x[col])
x[col] = np.where(x[col] == 0, 0, x[col])
```

There should be no overwrite problems (`nan` converted to 0 aside) because `i > 0`, `i == 0`, and `i < 0` are all mutually exclusive for real numbers `i`.

---

You could composite all your functions with something like this:

```
s = df['score'].copy()
df['score'] = np.where(
    s > 0, s.rank(pct=True, method='average'),
    np.where(
        s < 0, 0.5,
        0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do what your question asks:

```py
df['y'] = (df.x < 0) * 0.5 + (df.x > 0) * df.x.rank()
```

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [-2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['y'] = (df.x < 0) * 0.5 + (df.x > 0) * df.x.rank()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   x    y
0 -2  0.5
1 -1  0.5
2  0  0.0
3  0  0.0
4  1  5.0
5  2  6.0
6  3  7.0
7  4  8.0
```